# Retrieving a value that is stored as MB

Tags: c#

I have a table that stores the amount of RAM a server has in a `biginit` column with values such as 2470208.

But how I can apply a data annotation or other validations to show only 2 instead of s470208. ?

I mean to always divide by 1 million and get the number on the left side of the digit ?

Comment: Are you asking for something other than "integer division" (2470208 / 1000000 = 2)? If so, what?

Comment: if the value is stored in mega bytes you should divide by 1024 instead of 1 million.

Comment: @nozari - it depends if he sells something or not - you know HDD "megabytes" are smaller than programmers' ones. :)

Answer (score 2):

1) Use this for automatic thousands-unit:

```
string GetByteString(long n) {
    int k=0;
    string u=" kMGTEP";
    while(n>1024) {
        n>>=10;
        k++;
    }
    return n.ToString() + u[k];
}
```

Call:

```
string s= GetByteString(1234567890123);
Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

2) But if you simply always want MB just shift by 20:

```
long n = 123456789;
string MB = (n>>20).ToString();
```

But this will show 0 if `n` goes below 1MB.

Reason:

```
1 kB = 2^10 = 1<<10 = 1024;  
1 MB = 2^20 = 1<<20 = 1024*1024 = 1048576;  
1 GB = 2^30 = 1<<30 = 1024*1024*1024 = 1073741824;
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged C# but mentioned a bigint column so it isn't clear whether you're looking for a database or C# solution.  The following C# method will take the number of bytes as an integer and return a formatted string...

```
public string FormattedBytes(long bytes)
{
    string units = " kMGT";
    double logBase = Math.Log((double)bytes, 1024.0);
    double floorBase = Math.Floor(logBase);

    return String.Format("{0:N2}{1}b",
        Math.Pow(1024.0, logBase - floorBase),
        units.Substring((int)floorBase, 1));
}
```